# Flutter bloc library - how to define the state objects

Tags: flutter

I’ve been using the Provider package for state management in my apps so far and is working great but I can see the benefits of using the bloc_library package for some more maintainable and predictable state management.

I am struggling with figuring out how to construct the state object in the following scenario:
Let’s say I have a page where I display the food journal for a user in a specific day. When the user changes the date, I fetch the journal for the new day but I want to show the loading indicator on top of the current day, not replacing the entire screen with a loading widget. Similar, if I get an error when switching the day, I want to display an alert and remain on the current day.

Based on the above, I guess I cannot define a Loading or an Error state because I lose the current day state. 
Using the Provider package I have a PageState property with loading / error information besides other properties and I can easily build the UI based on that. 
Anyway, I have the impression that I’m missing something and I would appreciate any advice on how to leverage the BlocLibrary in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you will lose the current day state? You can define the state class like this

```
abstract class MyState {}

class Initial extends MyState {}

class Loading extends MyState {
  final Food food;

  Loading(this.food);
}

class Success extends MyState {
  final Food food;

  Success(this.food);
}

class Error extends MyState {
  final Food food;

  Error(this.food);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of that too, but I don't like the idea to pass and duplicate all the properties.  But I guess this is the boilerplate that comes with this approach. Again, thank you, I thought that I missed something in how to use the library.

Comment: How Loading and Success state will share the data? Do I need to pass every time the state changes from Loading to Success?

Comment: Yes pretty much, through the event that would yield Success state